# owl-carousel autoplay working locally, not on server

Tags: javascript, timeout, owl-carousel, autoplay

my owl-carousel content is autoplaying and working perfectly with the speed setting on local. Once I upload to my server, the autoplay doesnt work and my second owl-carousel reverts back to a very slow speed.

How can this be?

```
    $('.portfolio-slider').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:4000,
    navText:['<i class="ion-chevron-left"></i>','<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>'],
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
    }
})  
$('.clients-active').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    navText:['<i class="ion-chevron-left"></i>','<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>'],
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed:800,
    autoplayTimeout:2000,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2
        },
        450:{
            items:3
        },
        768:{
            items:4
        },
        1000:{
            items:6
        }
    }
})
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Check console for error, share link of life code if possible.

Comment: @InterviewSortout , the console is empty. I've checked a few google maps mistakes but now it's error-free. Still the owl-carousel speed setting do not take effect. I find it very strange.

Comment: share html+js complete code, what you have done so far.